# How to import functions from `src` for testing?

Tags: rust

I have been trying to understand how to import functions for testing in Rust for hours with no success. I have a project structure that looks like this:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│  ├── main.rs
│  └── funcs
│    ├── mod.rs
│    └── hello.rs
└── tests
   └── test_hello.rs
```

`src/funcs/mod.rs`:

```
pub mod hello;
```

`src/funcs/hello.rs`:

```
pub fn hello() {
    println!("{}", "hello!");
}
```

`src/main.rs`:

```
mod funcs;

fn main() {
    funcs::hello::hello(); // this works
}
```

`src/tests/test_hello.rs`

```
mod funcs; // this import does not work!

#[test]
fn add() {
    assert_eq!(2 + 2, 4);
}

#[test]
fn hello_test() {
    assert_eq!(funcs::hello::hello(), "hello");
}
```

How can I import public functions in `src` so that they can be used in my testing dir?

Comment: `mod` *defines* a module; it does not *import* a module. Use `use` to import a module. Should be something like `use crate::funcs;` in `test_hello.rs`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I use `use crate::funcs;` in `test_hello.rs`, I get the error: `unresolved import crate::funcs no funcs in the root`. I see `mod funcs` in `main.rs`, so I am not sure what that error means.

Comment: Make that `pub mod funcs;` in `main.rs` as Acorn suggests in a comment below.

Answer (score 8):

Create a `src/lib.rs` file to put most of the logic of your package into a library crate and export the `funcs` module there:

```
pub mod funcs;
```

Now use the library (which contains the module) from wherever you like. In your case, from both `src/main.rs` and `tests/test_hello.rs`:

```
use <crate>::funcs;
```

Replace `<crate>` with the name of your library crate which is the same as the package name and your root folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I move `pub mod funcs;` from `main.rs` to `lib.rs` both of which are in the same `src/` directory, I now get the error that `file not found for module funcs`. Rust further states that `help: to create the module `funcs`, create file "src/lib/funcs.rs"`.

Comment: Are you using the 2018 edition?

Comment: Yes, I am using the 2018 edition.

Comment: Strange, that should work.

Comment: My issue appears to be that I can't use `mod funcs` in `lib.rs`, but it works perfectly fine in `main.rs`. So far, I really like Rust the language, but imports/exports are really difficult to me.

Comment: It should be `pub mod funcs;`, since you want to access it from outside the library crate. I suggest starting from scratch and first making a simple binary + library package work, then add a module in its own file, then move it into its own folder, etc.

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for the help. I'll do that. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A Rust crate can contain a program and/or a library. Tests can only access a library, not a program (and only the public parts of the library). In your case you have only a program, so you can't have tests. In order for tests to work, you will need to:

- Split you code into a program (in the `main.rs` file) and a library (in the `lib.rs` file).
- Make sure that any part of the library that you want to use in the program is public.
- Make sure that any part of the library that you want to test is also public.
- In `main.rs` and in the tests, write `use foo::hello` to access the `hello` function, replacing `foo` with the name of your library.

If you want to split the code into modules, declare each module with `pub mod mod_name` in `lib.rs`, then import them with `use foo::mod_name;` in `main.rs` or in the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Rust considers tests as part of a separate crate, so you have to put `use your_crate_name::funcs;` at the top of your tests, where `your_crate_name` is the crate name of your main package as defined in `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In my Cargo.toml file, my main package is named `hello`. If I add `use hello::funcs;` to the top of  `test_hello.rs` file, I get the error: `use of undeclared type or module hello`;