# basic integration test in rust

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, integration-testing

Start learning rust, and got stuck when trying to test my code.... I think a scope problem..

```
!project structure
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── main.rs
│   ├── mymod
│   │   ├── mod.rs
│   │   └── operations.rs
│   └── mysub.rs
└── tests
    ├── mod.rs
    └── mymod_test.rs

Cargo.toml ------------
[package]
name = "sample01"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
--

main.rs ---------------
mod mymod;
mod mysub;
use mysub::mysub;
use mymod::operations::{mysum, mymul};
pub fn mydiv(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 { x/y }
fn main() {
    println!("my operators: 6, 2");
    let s:i32 = mysum(6,2);
    let m:i32 = mymul(6,2);
    let d:i32 = mydiv(6,2);
    let sb:i32 = mysub(6,2);
    println!("The value of the sum is: {s}");
    println!("The value of the mul is: {m}");
    println!("The value of the div is: {d}");
    println!("The value of the sub is: {sb}");
}
--

mysub.rs --------------
pub fn mysub(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 { x-y }
--

mymod/mod.rs ---------
pub mod operations;
--

mymod/operations.rs --
pub fn mysum(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 { x+y }
pub fn mymul(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 { x*y }
--

tests/mod.rs ---------
// ? could be tha same name as the module ?
pub mod mymod_test;
--

tests/mymod_test.rs --
use mymod::mysum;

#[test]
fn test_sum() {
    let s:i32 = mysum(2,3);
    assert_eq!(s, 5);
}
--
```

cargo run, runs ok, but cargo test appears not finding the subfolder.

tried on mymod_test.rs:

```
use crate::mymod::mysum;
use sample01::mymod::mysum;
use src::mymod::mysum;
use super::*;
```

without success :(. missing something?

```
   Compiling sample01 v0.1.0 (/<path>/sample01)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `mymod`
 --> tests/mymod_test.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use mymod::mysum;
  |     ^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `mymod`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `sample01` (test "mod") due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: could not compile `sample01` (test "mymod_test") due to previous error
```

links:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html

Comment: found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685938/how-to-import-functions-from-src-for-testing . Can anyone confirm I cant only do integration test on libs?

Comment: No, you can itegration test binaries as well, but integration testing a binary is *calling* the binary, for example with `Command`. Any functions of a binary crate are not part of it's API, so you can't use them from an integration test.